iPhone hotspot ‘using 2GB’ every time I connect a device!
I have an iPhone XS with iOS 14.
I am not sure how long this has been happening, but this is repeatable.
Every single time I connect my phone’s hotspot to my laptop, and just connect, mind you, and then check my mobile data usage, it reports that I have used an additional 2GB on my hotspot.
So I dove deeper in and realised that the out of the devices used, “other devices” have used all of mobile data for hotspot, because I hardly even ever connect my laptop.
How can I understand better what is using data through my mobile hotspot?

Do you use iCloud Photos or iCloud to backup your laptop?

@IconDaemon no I haven’t but no matter what my laptop could be trying to download- it “uses 2GB” even if I connect for literally 5 seconds.

Is it performing automatic updates? Did you check for malware on your laptop as well?

To get this more likely to gain traction, I’ve removed a bunch of chit chat. When you asked this, you said your iOS was updated. Please edit to list exactly what you’re using. There is always beta software and latest only is accurate for a short amount of time.

@FelixAn My iphone is at the latest iOS and my laptop is not. But even if there was malware (which seems unlikely,) it uses exactly 2GB even if I connect for 3 seconds! That seems almost impossible seeing as it’s mobile data, too.

@bmike Thanks for the edit- hopefully it should get more attention now. I will edit.
